# Why doesn't my Excel 365 does not cover the "LET()" worksheet function?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

My Excel account information shows me I'm working with Office 365:

[image]

However, the `LET()` worksheet function is not covered, as you can see:

[image]

What do I need to do in order to get this function to work? (According to [this URL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999), this function should work for Excel 365)

Comment: What build of Office 365 do you have installed?  Is it newer than 15928.20282 (2212)?  According to my research, if your build is newer than 15330.20264 (2206), the function should exist.

Comment: Check you have the latest version via *File > Account > Update Options > Update Now*.

Comment: I'm at build number ±12500. I tried to update but I failed (up to now), I have this error code: 30015-28 (2353463554)

Comment: Is this a company managed computer and Office subscription, or personal?

Comment: @music2myear: it's a personal one.

Comment: Please add this and the other information you've given to the question to make it better, clearer and more complete. Have you looked up that error message to see what you might do to resolve it and update your Office suite?

Comment: @music2myear: I only found that it's an internal error, not more.